# looping through uiimageview in customCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

hello i have product table and product details view for each product i have  many images that are downloaded and cached on disk and memory on each time user select a product to check its details i am trying to retrieving cached images and set it up for my Four **UIImageView** inside the a custom Cell in **UITableViewController** i am not able to set the images although i can log them through **NSLog()** function i am using this code:

```
    int index = 0;
    int indexOfImages = 1;
    self.imageCache = [[SDImageCache alloc] initWithNamespace:@"menuImage"];
   for ( UIImageView *currentImageView in cell.contentView.subviews)
    {
        NSLog(@"the imageindex is: %d",indexOfImages);
        NSLog(@"the index is: %d",index);
        NSLog(@"the count is: %lu",(unsigned long)[self.currentProduct.mirsaProductUrlImage count]);
        if (index < [self.currentProduct.mirsaProductUrlImage count] ) {
             [self.imageCache queryDiskCacheForKey:self.currentProduct.mirsaProductUrlImage[indexOfImages]  
    done:^(UIImage *image, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {
                if (image) {
                   currentImageView.image =  image;
                }
            }];
            indexOfImages++;
            index++;
         }
         else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
```

> and if i try to change the loop way to this

```
 for ( UIImageView *currentImageView in self.tableView.subViews)
```

> i got this error UITableViewWrapperView setImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

i just want to know if i am looping in a wrong way what i mean that i am not able to reach them through this loop or what is going on ?

Comment: It isn't clear what you are actually trying to achieve, but trying to access the subviews of your tableview almost certainly isn't the right way. Your exception occurs because not all of your  table's subviews are UIImageViews.

Comment: my friend i am trying to access all my UIImageView inside my customCell of UITableView how i can achieve that ?

Comment: yes, you said that, but it isn't clear *why* you would want to do such a thing. Your tableview cells are merely representations of your data model.  Are you trying to replace placeholder images with cached images that have been retrieved from the network after the cell has already been displayed?

Comment: @Paulw11 exactly my friend i know i am too bad in english:( i am so sorry

Comment: @Paulw11 yes i am trying to do what you are trying to say ? any solution for that ?

Comment: You would normally handle this in the network callback in your `cellForRow(atIndexPath:)` - can you show this function?

Comment: Yeah sure i am calling this at cellForRowAtIndexPath since i will not reach my cell if i am calling it outside of this function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to change the loop as :

```
 for ( UIView *currentView in cell.contentView.subviews)
   {
      if([currentView isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
      {
           // here Do All the stuff for imageViews
      }
   }
```

Do All this stuff in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`
and to change the imageView image take weak instance of imageView like this :

```
__weak UIImageView *weakImage = currentImageView;
 [self.imageCache queryDiskCacheForKey:self.currentProduct.mirsaProductUrlImage[indexOfImages]  
    done:^(UIImage *image, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {
                if (image) {
                    weakImage.image =  image;
                }
 }];
```

Comment: Exactly that what i did

Comment: Changing imageview instance to weak will take less memory.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this will not work with your code.
as

> for ( UIImageView *currentImageView in cell.contentView.subviews)

this line will try to convert all subviews of your cell's contentview to UIImageview.

You can set tag to all your UIImageview and then directly access them with tag like

cell.contentView.viewWithTag(*yourtag*)

and set image to it